# How do I migrate data from a SQL Server DB to MongoDB?

Tags: sql-server, mongodb

I wish to migrate a large SQL Server Database (having a million tables) to MongoDB. I am not able to understand **how to convert the complex Joins, indexes and keys in SQL Server to MongoDB** which has over a million tables and huge data?

Comment: You assume that the conversion SQL -> noSQL is possible without loss of functionality: *wrong*. SQL and noSQL have different (optimal) use-cases, although some funcionality overlaps, they're not interchangeable.

Comment: A million tables? Well, good luck with the migration process ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Joins you either pre-compute and store the denormalised data in the document. Or the application implements a join algorithm for runtime.

Indexes can be defined for whichever values inside the documents you'd like to have them. The documentation adequately  describes the options. As currently, they help reads but have a write overhead.

Keys: there are no keys. Each row has a unique identifier which you can assign or let the system generate a value. This would correspond to a surrogate primary key. Foreign keys, uniqueness, check constraints, assertions etc. are the appapplication's responsibility.

Answer (score -1):

The first step to migrating from SQL to NoSQL is to denormalize your schema since MongoDB does not support joins. You should be able to recreate the indices and keys in Mongo using JSON format. Also keep in mind that MongoDB **does not** support transactions.

You can check out this tool to help you move data between SQL and Mongo.
https://github.com/anlek/mongify

Comment: I tried using mongify but it is giving me error while running - "**mongify translation database.config > translation_file.rb**"

This is the Error->
**/home/zcon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:270:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem mongify (>= 0.a) (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
 from /home/zcon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:298:in `activate_bin_path'
 from /home/zcon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/mongify:22:in `<main>'**

Comment: are you using the correct mongify version? ihave mongify 1.3.0 with the ruby version you have. what do you get when you run mongify -v?

Comment: Not even getting the version of mongify. When I try to run **mongify -v**, I am getting the same error mentioned above even after uninstalling and installing it again.

Comment: Did you run `gem install mongify`?

Comment: yes..I ran **gem install mongify**